# getting changed uri on ContentObserver Onchange on older versions of the API

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contentobserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get URI of inserted row in my content observer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432800/how-to-get-uri-of-inserted-row-in-my-content-observer)

I am using ContentObserver to listen to changes on a content provider. However, I was wondering if there is a way to get the changed URI when the OnChange method is called (instead of doing a search query inside the callback in order to find out what has changed).

It seem that this is possible with the API level 16, but I have to write an API 8 compliant application =S

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. There is a different way of answering to this question for API 16 and APIs < 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, later I found the same question posted in other places and still without an answer, which leads me to think that there is just no way to get the changed URI on older apis.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I am also facing same problem. If you have found the solution then please share it. Please guide me.

Comment: I havent found any answer at that time and doing a quick google search also did not find any thing new since then... I think that your best bet is to get the `onChange(boolean)` with older apis, implement as `onChange(selfChange, null);` and on the new onChange, try to use some data on your database (such as a flag, date, etc) to figure it out which was the changed URI.