# How to utilize Uri parameter of onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) method?

Tags: android, sqlite

How can get the data from newly updated row from `Uri` given in `onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)` method?

I have found this but that didn't help much.

[How to get URI of inserted row in my content observer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432800/how-to-get-uri-of-inserted-row-in-my-content-observer)

Comment: if you have registered the observer, then the uri will point to the row itself.